# Error when trying to populate listbox

Tags: c#-3.0

Hi I am a student I am getting this error:

> forreach statement cannot operate on
>   variables of type 'object' because
>   'object' does not contain a public
>   definition for 'GetEnumerator'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string result = " ";
            foreach (string activity in listBox1.SelectedItems)
            {
                result += activity + "   ";
            }
            this.textBox1.Text = result;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox2.Text);
            textBox2.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Pl. help me

Comment: Your code looks good to me. Are you sure you posted the same code causing the issue ? What's the line causing the error ?

Comment: Maybe you confuse the `SelectedItem` method that gets the only one selected item from the ListBox with the `SelectedItems` method that returns a collection of selected items?

Comment: Works fine for me in 4.0 -- I wonder if SelectedItems was different in 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine for me.  However, your code will break if you've added something other than a `string` to your `ListBox`'s `Items` collection (although this will produce a different error than what you're apparently seeing).

Can you add the code you use to populate this ListBox?